# Finding a Pattern in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, pattern-matching

I am trying to clean some data. Below is an example of my data.

```
   test1          test2         test3    
 jsb cjn       kd N069W j        N9DSW
```

I want to indicate what column has the pattern N0{num}{num}W in it. The {num} part can be any number between 0-9. This pattern can also appear anywhere in the string. Hence in this case my results would be as follows.

```
   test1          test2         test3     col
 jsb cjn       kd N069W j        N9DSW      2
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also use the function `str_detect()` from the library **stringr**.

```
library(stringr)
str_detect('kd NO69W j', pattern = "NO\\d+W")
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I am assuming d+w looks for digits, out of curiosity how would you search for any letters between a-z? @demarsylvain

Comment: You can look for "regular expression". The argument `pattern =` will accept most of them (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.3.1/topics/str_detect). 
For instance, `str_detect(character_value, pattern = "[a-zA-Z]")`

Answer (score 4):

We loop through the columns, use `grepl` to get a logical index and then with `max.col` get the column index of each row

```
max.col(data.frame(lapply(df1, grepl, pattern = "N0\\d{2}W")))
#[1] 2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(test1 = "jsb cjn", test2 = "kd N069W j", 
 test3 = "N9DSW"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -1L))
```

Comment: If the pattern seems to have 2 digits, shouldn't the regex be `"NO\\d\\dW"`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply`:

```
df$col <- apply(df, 1, function(x) grep("N0\\d{2}W", x))
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(test1 = structure(1L, .Label = "jsb cjn", class = "factor"), 
    test2 = structure(1L, .Label = "kd N069W j", class = "factor"), 
    test3 = structure(1L, .Label = "N9DSW ", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```